# What do people mean by "Divide unity by something" in Math?

Tags: soft-question

I was reading a book, and on one page it said:

> Let the series$$S=A+Bx+Cx^2+Dx^3+Ex^4+Fx^5+\ldots+\&c\tag1$$
>   Divide unity by $S$ as far as two terms of the quotient, which will be the form $p+qx$, and write the remainder in the form $\ldots$

The book also included an example:

> $\ldots $$$S=1+3x+6x^2+10x^3+15x^4+21x^5+\ldots\&c\tag2$$
> Then, we shall have $\frac 1S=1-3x+\ldots$ with a remainder
> $$3x^2+8x^3+15x^4+21x^5+\&c\tag3$$
>
> $$\vdots$$

**Questions:**

1. What did the book mean by "Divide unity by $S$? Do they mean take the reciprocal of $S$, or something entirely different? I do know that unity means $1$, so we're dividing by $1$ somewhere.
2. How did the book get $\frac 1S=1-3x+\ldots\&c$?

---

At this point, I am kind of baffled by what they mean. I spent almost half an hour on this, and just *cannot figure it out*!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "Unity" is another way of referring to the number "1". So "divide unity by S" means "take the reciprocal of S".

Comment: Hint: use $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots$ and make some substitutions.

Comment: More generally  unity is the multiplicative identity (the number u for were x = ux)

Comment: For $\frac 1 S$, the coefficient of $x^4$ should equals $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1:

For$|x|<1$,
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k}=\frac {1}{1-x}.$$
$$f(1-S)=\frac {1}{S}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-S)^{k}.$$
Then,
$$\frac {1}{S}=1+(1-S)+(1-S)^2+(1-S)^3+\ldots$$
$$=1+(-3x-6x^2-10x^3-\ldots)+(-3x-6x^2-10x^3-\ldots)^2+(-3x-6x^2-10x^3-\ldots)^3+\ldots$$
$$=1+(\color{red}{-3x}\color{blue}{-6x^2}\color{green}{-10x^3}-\ldots)+(\color{blue}{9x^2}\color{green}{+36x^3}+60x^4+36x^4-\ldots)+(\color{green}{-27x^3}+\ldots)+\ldots$$
$$=1\color{red}{-3x}\color{blue}{+3x^2}\color{green}{-x^3}+\ldots$$

---

### Method 2:

Let $\frac 1 S =a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\ldots$.
$$S\cdot \frac 1 S=(1+3x+6x^2+10x^3+\ldots)(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\ldots)$$
$$=a_0+(3a_0+a_1)x+(6a_0+3a_1+a_2)x^2+(10a_0+6a_1+3a_2+a_3)x^3+\ldots=1$$
Therefore,
\begin{array}{cccc} 
&~~~~a_0&&&&&& &=1 \\  
&~~3a_0&+&~a_1&&&&&=0 \\ 
&~~6a_0&+&3a_1&+&~a_2&&&=0 \\ 
&10a_0&+&6a_1&+&3a_2&+&~a_3&=0 \\  
\end{array}
$$\ldots\ldots$$

$\therefore a_0=1, a_1=-3, a_2=3,a_3=-1, \ldots$

$$\frac 1 S=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdot\cdot\cdot=1-3x+3x^2-x^3+\ldots.$$

---

### Method 3:

Rewrite **unity** $1$ as $1+0x+0x^2+0x^3+\ldots$.


$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad ~1-3x+3x^2-~~x^3~+\ldots$

$~~1+3x+6x^2+10x^3+\ldots\overline{)1+0x+0x^2+~0x^3+\ldots }$

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad 1+3x+6x^2+10x^3+\ldots$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\overline{-3x-6x^2-10x^3+\ldots} $

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad-3x-9x^2-18x^3+\ldots$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\overline{3x^2+~~8x^3+\ldots} $

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad3x^2+~~9x^3+\ldots $

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\overline{-x^3+\ldots}$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad-x^3+\ldots$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\overline{\ldots} $

$$\therefore \frac 1 S=1-3x+3x^2-x^3+\ldots$$

---

Choose one of the methods you like :)

Comment: The book hasn't introduced us to any other infinite series, such as $f(1-S)=\frac 1S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-S)^k$. They just said $S=1+3x+6x^2+10x^3+\ldots\&c$ and declared $\frac 1S=1-3x+\ldots$ with a remainder. Any other ideas on how they came up with that?

Comment: This is new answer :)

Comment: Hm... But $$\dfrac 1S=1-3x+3x^2+8x^3+15x^4+24x^5+\ldots+\&c$$Any ideas on what went wrong?

Comment: I think maybe David K's interpretation on the question is correct. $21x^5$ is just a transcription error.

Comment: Generally, when finding the reciprocal of a polynomial, you can consider these methods :)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably they're thinking of dividing $1$ by $S$ with a quotient $Q(x)$ and remainder $R(x)$ such that
$$
1 = (Q(x))S + R
$$
where $Q$ is a polynomial of some degree $n$, chosen so that
it "cancels" the terms of degree $0, \ldots, n-1$ in the division,
so $R$ is a series starting with a term in $x^n$.
For $S = 1+3x+\cdots$ and for $Q(x)$ of degree $1$ (so $Q(x)=p+qx$),
we can work out $Q$ by synthetic division. After two steps we have this:
\begin{align}
    & \phantom{)\ } 1  -  3x  + \cdots \\
1+3x+6x^2+10x^3+15x^4+21x^5+\cdots \ &
     \overline{)\ 1 \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad} \\
    & \phantom{)\ } \underline{1+3x+6x^2+10x^3+15x^4+21x^5+\cdots}\\
    & \phantom{)\ 1} -3x-6x^2-10x^3-15x^4-21x^5+\cdots\\
    & \phantom{)\ 1} \underline{{}-3x-9x^2-18x^3-30x^4-45x^5+\cdots}\\
    & \phantom{)\ 1-3x-{}} 3x^2+\phantom{1}8x^3+15x^4+24x^5+\cdots\\
\end{align}

In other words,
\begin{multline}
1 = (1 - 3x)(1+3x+6x^2+10x^3+15x^4+21x^5+\cdots) + {}\\
(3x^2+8x^3+15x^4+24x^5+\cdots),
\end{multline}
so the remainder is $3x^2+8x^3+15x^4+24x^5+\cdots$.

I notice that the $x^5$ term in my remainder is different from what
is written in the question, but that could just be a transcription
error somewhere.

Comment: After some messing around, I get the generating function for $S=2+4x+6x^2+8x^3+10x^4+12x^5+\ldots$ as $S=\dfrac 2{1-2x-4x^2}$ which is wrong. The computer says it's $S=\dfrac 2{(1-x)^2}$. After checking it repeatedly, I didn't find anything wrong! Could you double check my answer?

Comment: ***My work:*** $S=2+4x+6x^2+8x^3+10x^4+12x^5+\ldots$ so $\dfrac 1S=\dfrac 12-1$ and we have $S'=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+\ldots$. Dividing again we get $\dfrac S{S'}=2$ and a remainder of $0$. Hence, $S=\dfrac 1{\dfrac 12-x-2x^2}=\dfrac 2{1-2x-4x^2}$.